# IF formula do not return anything

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a Google sheet where I receive the data automatically from a software. Basically it adds a new row and with data in each column. Now I have to add manually a column and I want to add a formula to each new row. I'm using IF to leave the cell blank if G1401 is empty.

```
=if(G1401="", , ifna(CONCATENATE(G1401," - ",H1401," - ",J1401)))
```

But i have to drag the formula for the cells I want and thats THE problem. If I drag the formula, when the software sends a new row, it's assuming that I already have a row filled with a formula and write in the next one without the formula.

What I want is something similar to FILTER function to be able to not use the drag cell formula to use it or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use in row 2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(G2:G="",, G2:G&" - "&H2:H&" - "&J2:J))
```

Comment: Can't believe is that simple.